# Excel and use OR in a SUMIFS function

Tags: worksheet-function

I am using this function.

```
=IF(ISNUMBER(SEARCH("LOS",$A6))=TRUE,$C6,"")
```

However I really want to look for "LOS" OR "DTS".  Can this be done with the SUMIFS Function? If yes, please show an example.

Comment: Sumifs is for a range of cells, you are testing only one.  Do you want to do a range of Cells?

Answer (score 1):

If you are testing only one cell I would use COUNTIF with a SUMPRODUCT wrapper:

```
=IF(SUMPRODUCT(COUNTIF($A6,{"*LOS*","*DTS*"})),$C6,"")
```

This will effectively run two COUNTIF()s and sum their results.  COUNTIF() allows the use of WildCards.  IF either is found it will return a value of >0 and the IF will see that as True and return the value in C6.

If, in fact, you want to sum all of C:C where A:A has those two strings then yes a SUMIF will work:

```
=SUMPRODUCT(SUMIF(C:C,A:A,{"*LOS*","*DTS*"}))
```

Like the COUNTIF() this will do two SUMIF()s and return the sum of both.  One will look for all the values in A that have `LOS` and the other `DTS` and return the sum of the matches.

If the cell has both `LOS` and `DTS` the value in C will be added twice.